# Changing properties of MenuBarExtra icon

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to create a MenuBarExtra that allows for the icon to be a different colour depending on a bool. Something like [This](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-menu-bar-app/) but with a colour change instead of the number inside the icon.

I'm having trouble with recolouring the icon as the MenuBarExtra initializer asks for a string instead of a view (which I am trying to pass in the form of an Image with property changes)

Here is what I want:

```
MenuBarExtra("label", systemImage: Image(systemName: "circle").foregroundColor(.red))
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'String'
```

I am able to pass "circle" as an argument for systemImage, but not the image. Is there any way to change systemImage properties when a string is required?

Comment: can you share the whole code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took me a long time to figure out how to change the size. But finally I made it.

```
@State var isInserted = true
@State var colorIndex = 0
let colors: [NSColor] = [.red, .blue, .orange]
MenuBarExtra(isInserted: $isInserted) {
    Button("Shift") {
        colorIndex = (colorIndex+1) % colors.count
    }
} label: {
    let configuration = NSImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .light)
                .applying(.init(paletteColors: [colors[colorIndex]]))
    let image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "camera", accessibilityDescription: nil)
    let updateImage = image?.withSymbolConfiguration(configuration)
    Image(nsImage: updateImage!)
}
```

Comment: This works. The accepted answer does not work. This should be the accepted answer.