# How to change the text color of a MenuBarExtra label?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to change the text color of a `MenuBarExtra` label.

[I came across a Stack Overflow post earlier that gives a solution for changing the color of an SF Symbol used as a label for a `MenuBarExtra`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000325/changing-properties-of-menubarextra-icon) I am trying to implement something similar, but for text.

In my case, I have a label consisting of an `HStack`, an `Image`, and `Text`. I want the color of both the `Image` and `Text` to be red. So far, I am only able to change the color of the `Image`. Using normal SwiftUI modifiers does not work last time I checked. How can I get text to show up as red?

My code is below:

```
MenuBarExtra {
    Text("Hello.")
        .padding(12)
} label: {
    HStack {
        let configuration = NSImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .light)
                .applying(.init(hierarchicalColor: .red))
                
        let image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "moon.stars.fill", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        let updateImage = image?.withSymbolConfiguration(configuration)

        Image(nsImage: updateImage!) // This works.

        let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .light)
        let color = NSColor.red // Attempting to make the text red.
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .foregroundColor: color
        ]

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, world!", attributes: attributes)
                
        Text(AttributedString(attributedString)) // This doesn't work.
    }
}
```

This is what the MenuBarExtra label looks like currently:

[image: Image of MenuBarExtra label.]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I’m trying to change the font and suspect it will be a similar solution.

Comment: @JamesAmner Sadly I still cannot find a solution. I have tried different methods using `NSAttributedString`, but no dice.

Comment: I looked for a solution or this a long while ago, tried everything I could think of with NSAttributedString and never got it. Thought I'd give it another go. I have it working in a non-swiftUI context, but was trying to go full SwiftUI. I guess we're at a limitation of SwiftUI for now...

Comment: @JamesAmner What was the non-SwiftUI context you came up with? I'm desperate at this point lol.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jdamner/14c01237c31e76c5bf2433b5d4f22df5

Comment: For me I want a monospaced font, applying colours in the same way should work just fine though.

Comment: @JamesAmner Just to clarify, where in your SwiftUI project did you write this?